# Зависает команда rbd ls на Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, vmware

Речь о RADOS Block Device. После поднятия Ceph-кластера на Vmware + Ubuntu, пытаюсь выполнить команду rbd ls или rbd create, команда запускается и не завершается. При этом ничего не делает судя по цпу, и висит куча rbd форков-бездельников. Кто-нибудь с таким сталкивался?

Поднимаю кластер в первый раз, вроде поднялся:

```
root@node1:/etc/ceph# ceph -s
cluster 79e95a39-e056-48f8-b8e7-d5b43ecca7d2
 health HEALTH_WARN 192 pgs incomplete; 192 pgs stuck inactive; 192 pgs stuck unclean; 1 requests are blocked > 32 sec
 monmap e3: 3 mons at {node1=192.168.1.11:6789/0,node2=192.168.1.12:6789/0,node3=192.168.1.13:6789/0}, election epoch 6, quorum 0,1,2 node1,node2,node3
 osdmap e10: 3 osds: 3 up, 3 in
  pgmap v23: 192 pgs, 3 pools, 0 bytes data, 0 objects
        101608 kB used, 15227 MB / 15326 MB avail
             192 creating+incomplete
```

Comment: А в логах что происходит?

Comment: поисковый запрос *rbd ls hangs* даёт много (возможно полезной) информации.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте посмотреть текущие сетевые соединения при выполнении этих команд.

`netstat -ntpa`

Вполне возможно, что в их списке будут соединения в состоянии SYN_SENT. Значит, вы не открыли порты 6789 на мониторах.